# Después de cargar una tabla en ASP NET el evento de Bootstrap para ocultar y mostrar el menú lateral no responde

Tags: asp.net, eventos, gridview

Me encuentro realizado una pagina web y estoy un con problemita.

Cuando inicio la pagina desde Visual Studio el funcionamiento del evento de mostrar y ocultar el menú esta funcional puedo cambiar de pagina y sigue funcionando, deja de funcionar cuando termina de cargar un gridview, quiero ocultar o mostrar el menú y no responde, vuelvo a refrescar la pantalla y vuelve a funcionar el evento.

me podrían ayudar con este problemita.

muchas gracias.